# see if item exists in a select element with jquery/PHP

Tags: php, jquery

This is a bizarre request but i have two select elements on my page, one for old project numbers and one for new project numbers. I am using PHP to populate the dropdowns from a mysql db. I have also set up a GET variable which will hold an incoming project number from a hyperlink people click on another page. But what i want to do is use jQuery/PHP to take that incoming project number and see if it exists in either of the dropdowns?

This is the GET code:

```
<?php echo $_GET['project_no']; ?>
```

Comment: By drop-down, do you really mean a [`select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6) element?

Comment: Yeah sorry. its just what i call them (apologies)

Comment: No problem, but you might want to edit your question to use the name (most) other people call them by... =b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a JavaScript variable with PHP:

```
<?php
/*... other php */
echo 'var projectNumber = "' . $_GET['project_no'] . '";';
/*... other php */
?>
```

Which renders to:

```
var projectNumber = "12345"; // or whatever value 'project_no' might contain
```

And then, in jQuery:

```
$('select > option:contains(' + projectNumber + ')').attr('selected',true);
```

This, obviously, selects the value. You could just as easily use an `if` statement of some sort, though. It depends on what you wanted to do with the values, if found.

---

**Edited** to add the following selector, which is slightly more meaningful, and uses a slightly more obvious [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector), though this doesn't look at the text, which the previous example, with [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) does:

```
$('select > option[value=' + projectNumber + ']').attr('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to interate through the `option` nodes and compare the values.

```
function lookup(check, cb) {
    $('#somedropdown').find('option').each(function(index, elem) {
        if( elem.value === check ) {
            cb();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(data) {
         lookup(data.project_name_for_instance, function() {
              // match
         });
    },
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**view online demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/APXGv/

```
//jQuery sweetness
if($("#dropdown option[value='<?php echo $_GET['project_no']; ?>'").size()){
    alert("exists");
    //your code here...
}
```